# Legend of Zelda: Four Swords not showing up on Nintendo eShop

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, zelda-four-swords-anniversary-ed

Supposedly, you can download The Legend Of Zelda: Four Swords for free until Feb 2.  http://zelda.com/fourswordsanniversary/

It worked on my son's Nintendo 2DS, but not on my other son's machine. They are exactly the same. I have modified the parental controls to be identical, but it's not showing up in the eShop for the 2nd 2DS by search or otherwise.

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on to force it to reconnect?

Comment: turned it off and on, connection is good. To be clear, I can see and download other games.

Comment: Sorry, I'm all out of ideas . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. The machine was set to Anguilla in the region settings. I changed it to United States and was able to download the game. Poor Anguillians.

Comment: Ah, yes, the game is only available to people in North America, so that is where your problem would have been.